# JW Angular Pagination Doesn't Work if used in Feature Module

Tags: node.js, angular, pagination, angular-module, angular-pagination

I'm using Angular 10 and the JW Angular Pagination module works fine if I import it into app.module.ts and then use it in a view that uses the app.component.ts component.  However, when I try to import it into a custom feature module and use a component that imports the feature module, the pagination element does not display in the view template. It seems that Angular cannot see the pagination module.

**App.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreModule } from "./core/core.module"
import { MessageModule } from "./messages/message.module";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AuthService } from "./model/auth.service"
import { JwPaginationModule } from 'jw-angular-pagination';






@NgModule({
  imports: [AppRoutingModule, MessageModule, CoreModule, BrowserModule, JwPaginationModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent,],  
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Core.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ModelModule } from "../model/model.module";
import { FormsFeatureModule } from "../view/forms.module";
import { ViewFeatureModule } from "../view/view.module";
import { routing } from "../app.routing";
import { MessageModule } from "../messages/message.module";
import { MessageService } from "../messages/message.service";
import { Message } from "../messages/message.model";
import { AuthService } from "../model/auth.service";
import { EncrDecrService } from '../utils/EncrDecr.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';



//import { NotFoundComponent } from "./notFound.component";
//import { UnsavedGuard } from './unsaved.guard';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ModelModule, MessageModule, routing, FormsFeatureModule, ViewFeatureModule, CommonModule],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [ModelModule, FormsFeatureModule, ViewFeatureModule, MessageModule ],
  providers: [AuthService, EncrDecrService],
  
})


export class CoreModule {
  
}
```

**Forms.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule, Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
//import { NotFoundComponent } from "./notFound.component";
//import { UnsavedGuard } from './unsaved.guard';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthService } from "../model/auth.service";
import { JwPaginationModule } from 'jw-angular-pagination';


@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule, RouterModule, JwPaginationModule],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule, JwPaginationModule],
  providers: [AuthService],
  
})


export class FormsFeatureModule {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

**View.module.ts**

```
import { RecipeViewComponent } from "../view/recipeView.component";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePageComponent } from "./homePage.component";
import { AdminComponent } from "../admin/admin.component";
import { AuthService } from "../model/auth.service";
//import { NotFoundComponent } from "./notFound.component";
//import { UnsavedGuard } from './unsaved.guard';


@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [RecipeViewComponent, HomePageComponent, AdminComponent],
  exports: [RecipeViewComponent, HomePageComponent,AdminComponent, RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthService],
  
})


export class ViewFeatureModule { }
```

**admin.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, DoCheck, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ModelRepo } from "../model/repository.model";
import { Category } from "../model/category.model";
import { Ingredient } from "../model/ingredient.model";
import { RecipeBook } from "../model/recipeBook.model";
import { User } from "../model/user.model";
import { FormsFeatureModule } from "../view/forms.module"
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { EncrDecrService } from '../utils/EncrDecr.service';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component'
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";


//import { MODES, SharedState, SHARED_STATE } from "./sharedState.model";
//import { Observer} from "rxjs"


@Component(



  {
    selector: "admin",
    templateUrl: "admin.component.html"
  }

)


export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
 ModNewCategory = new Category(0,"");
  ModNewIngredient = new Ingredient(0,"");
  ModNewRecipeBook = new RecipeBook();
  selectedConfig = "categories"; //initilze for first page load
  selectedCategoryOperation = "addCategory"; //initilze for first page load
  selectedIngredientOperation = "addIngredient"; //initilze for first page load
  selectedUserOperation = "addUser"; //initilze for first page load
  userRoles = new Array<string>("visitor", "member", "administrator");
  searchRole = "";
  id;
  mode;
  operation;
  defaultObject = new Object();
  public pageOfItems: Array<any>;
  public items = [];

  constructor(public dataRepo: ModelRepo, private EncrDecr: EncrDecrService, private appComponent:AppComponent, activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router, public fieldValidator: FormsFeatureModule) {
    
    activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {

      this.id = params["id"];
      this.mode = params["mode"];
      this.operation = params["operation"]
      if (this.operation != null && this.mode != null) {
        this.modifyItem(this.id, this.operation);
      }
     
    }
   
    )
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // an example array of 150 items to be paged
  //  this.items = this.dataRepo.users;
    this.items = Array(150).fill(0).map((x, i) => ({ id: (i + 1), name: `Item ${i + 1}` }));
   
  }

  onChangePage(pageOfItems: Array<any>) {
    // update current page of items
    alert('onChangePage got called');
    this.pageOfItems = pageOfItems;
  }
```

**admin.component.html**

```
   <div class="card text-center m-3">
      <h3 class="card-header">Angular  Pagination Example</h3>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div *ngFor="let item of pageOfItems">{{item.name}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer pb-0 pt-3">
        <jw-pagination [items]="items" (changePage)="onChangePage($event)"></jw-pagination>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: did you get any error in the console

Comment: No, there is no error or warning in the console

Comment: Can you share where you have declared admin.component.ts

Comment: @OwenKelvin I have included my module code above to provide more insight into the application structure.  I import all of my feature modules into one core module in core.module.ts.  I then import the core module into app.module.ts.   To answer your question, I've declared admin.component.ts in view.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

You are using Angular10...

Have a look at the below statement [Ivy is not complaining about unknown element inside ng-template
#36171](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36171)

> This is due to an architectural change in Ivy. In the previous compiler (ViewEngine), the check for unknown elements would occur during parsing of the template. In Ivy, templates are parsed independently from the corresponding `NgModule`, so information on components/directives in scope is not available.
> Instead, checking of elements is pushed into the template type checking phase and it's currently affected by the type checker's configuration. With `fullTemplateTypeCheck` set to `true` however, it should descend into templates to check them (when it's false, it won't for backwards compatibility reasons). This conflicts however with your statement here:
> The issue can only be found in runtime (no component being rendered) or with `fullTemplateTypeCheck: true`.

Consider the imports array in the module you are declaring `AdminComponent`

```
imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule, RouterModule],
```

This module does not have any idea about a `JwPaginationModule`

### Solution

The simplest solution is to simply add `JwPaginationModule` to this array

```
imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule, RouterModule, JwPaginationModule],
```

Now the module will know about this component and render correctly.